# AsyncTask Dialog Not Dismissed

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

I'm getting some data with an async task but it's always showing on the screen and never dismisses or hides. Why?

```
public class getJson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(kategori.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false); // ProgressDialog u iptal edilemez hale getirdik.
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... unused) {
        String resString = "";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://*********.com/api.asp?cmd=katdok&ID="+talepKategori);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity;
            entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+ "\n");
            }
            resString = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually hit to onPostExecute ? is pDialog.dismiss(); called ?

Comment: replace pDialog = new ProgressDialog(kategori.this); with pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); it was worked for me for the same issue. hope it may help you

Comment: Try removing "super.onPostExecute(string);". Maybe it's blocking the dismiss(). Or at least Debug the onPostExecute() and check if dismiss() is being called.

Comment: Not working this comments.. - (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the following method to ensure the Dialog is dismiss once the task has completed,

```
private void hideProgress() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

It avoids getting a null and forcibly closes a dialog.

Comment: Can you update the post with full class code? I think the progress dialog is getting called even after the onPostExecute() method.

Comment: I send you a mail. I found your mail adress from your web site.

Comment: Got the issue. You are using getJson() AsyncTask twice at the same time, one inside the populateListItesm() and another inside a try catch block. What happened is those two AsyncTask launched together and for some reason the progress dialog is still visible because the AsyncTask created them two times. Solution is preety simple, Call hideProgress() method at the beginning of populateListItesm(). Secondly Add another hideProgress() at the beginning of try block (before calling the getJson()) so that It will dismiss any previous dialog before creating a new one from the onPreExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
public class getJson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(kategori.this,
                    getResources().getText(R.string.app_name), getResources()
                    .getText(R.string.wait_message), true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... unused) {
        String resString = "";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://*********.com/api.asp?cmd=katdok&ID="+talepKategori);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity;
            entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+ "\n");
            }
            resString = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
        super.onPostExecute(string);
        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```